# webpack Rule.include can not work when package is installed by pnpm

Tags: webpack, pnpm

In my webpack output file, @react-spring is bundled as following:

```
/*!*******************************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/.pnpm/@react-spring+animated@9.1.2_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@react-spring/animated/index.js ***!
  \*******************************************************************************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {
```

react-spring is release with es6, I need make the my project support es5, so I have to add react-spring in babel-loader `include`.

```
// babel-loader config

      include: [resolve('../src'), resolve('../node_modules/react-spring'), resolve('../node_modules/@react-spring')],
      exclude: [resolve('../node_modules')],
```

Unfortunately，this config can not work, as the folder of pnpm package is nested. What can I try next?